# can a DFA have an arrow with empty string as input?

Tags: dfa, nfa, automaton

I've seen a picture of an automata represented as a DFA but it has arrows that has nothing on it!
What do these arrows mean in DFA? I mean are they different from epsilon (ε) , because we do not have ε in DFA ! what are they doing ?
And sorry if my question is a bit weird.[image: Is that a DFA ?!]

Comment: If it has empty transitions, then it is an ε-NFA.

Comment: It's certainly not a fully-specified DFA anyway since not all states have all transitions defined. You'd need to have some pretty well-understood conventions for this diagram to represent a deterministic finite automaton... perhaps if (1) missing transitions are understood to go to an unnamed dead state (2) missing labels are understood to be whichever input symbol is unaccounted for... maybe then this could represent a DFA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implied alphabet is {0,1}.  So for states with two transitions out, only one needs to be marked, as is the case.  If that one is marked "0", the other one is implicitly a 1.  If that one is marked "1", the other one is implicitly a 0.  For states with one transitions out, that transition represents (1,0).